# Woocommerce list of category and sub category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display list of WooCommerce product categories like Bellow:

```
category 1
  -subcategory 1
  -subcategory 2
  -subcategory 3
  -subcategory 4
  +show more
category 2
  -subcategory 1
  -subcategory 2
  -subcategory 3
  -subcategory 4
  -subcategory 5
  -subcategory 6
  -subcategory 7
  -subcategory 8

  -less more
```

When user clicks on the "show more" link, then Other categories are displayed.
and When user clicks on the "less more" link then Other categories are hidden.

any plugin or custom code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes, i have use "yith-woocommerce-category-accordion" plugin, but it not any solution for "show more" link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this case with "[Nextend Accordion Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/)" plugin!

I created a menu of product categories with wordpress "Menu" Then I used the plugin to display it correctly.